# Scrolling like WhatsApp Chat where scrolling to top, scrolling further shows "Archived Chats"

Tags: swift, uitableview

Just not getting the proper search term, but my question is how can i achieve this tableview feature where i can scroll to top, but only on further scrolling to top, a row appears on top of the first row.

Similar feature where WhatsApp uses to show "Archived Chats", here scrolling to your chat list, further scrolling shows you Archived chats.

I am using swift 2.3

Thank you

Comment: have you ever managed to implement it?

Comment: did you implement it ?

Comment: @jbouaziz No i have not implemented

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late, but here you have a workaround (objective-c) to replicate the whatsapp archived chats scroll further feature:

I use two booleans to determine if table view is at top position and if the archived chats row is visible.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isArchivedChatsRowVisible;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isScrollAtTop;
```

And with the scroll view delegate, using these bools, insert or remove a section for displaying the archive chats cell.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.isArchivedChatsRowVisible) {
        self.isScrollAtTop = NO;
        self.isArchivedChatsRowVisible = NO;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }

    if (self.isScrollAtTop && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && !self.isArchivedChatsRowVisible) {
        self.isArchivedChatsRowVisible = YES;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {      
    self.isScrollAtTop = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 ? NO : YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        self.isScrollAtTop = NO;
    }
}
```

I hope it would be useful

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version of @cmacera's answer. I've opted to use a `tableHeaderView` to achieve the same result.

Kudos to them, a nice simple solution. Now in Swift.

State variables:

```
var isArchivedChatsRowVisible: Bool = false
var isScrollAtTop: Bool = true
```

Scroll view delegate methods.

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        isScrollAtTop = false
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrollAtTop = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 ? false : true
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0, isArchivedChatsRowVisible {
        isScrollAtTop = false
        isArchivedChatsRowVisible = false
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    if isScrollAtTop, scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0, !isArchivedChatsRowVisible {
        isArchivedChatsRowVisible = true
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = archivedChatHeaderView
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement UIScrollview's delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`. IF you are setting tableview's delegate to `self` or you have implemented or confirmed `UITableViewDelegate` then you will automatically conform `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocall because `UITableViewDelegate` implements `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

In your `scrollViewDidScroll`,

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    UITableView *tab = (UITableView *)scrollView;

    if (self.yourTableView == tab) {

            // Detect Scroll position and add button or do whatever you want
      }
 }
```

Comment: While the problem seems easy to solve, your reply is just a piece of it and more details of your proposed solution would be great.